Vertically center an Icon
I want to center my Icons in their Rows. I tried already the verticalAlignment parameter of the Row but it seems to work only on the Text:
Row(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
) {
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Email,
        tint = TextColor1,
        contentDescription = "email icon",
    )
    Text(
        text = stringResource(R.string.mail_adress),
        color = TextColor1,
        fontSize = 20.sp,
    )
}

code image + what it's doing:

I know that it is close to be centered but it is not perfectly centered.

Edit:
Here is the full code if needed (I kept only the problematic part):
package com.example.cartedevisite2

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Email
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.cartedevisite2.ui.theme.BackgroundColor
import com.example.cartedevisite2.ui.theme.CarteDeVisite2Theme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CarteDeVisite2Theme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    VisitCard()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun VisitCard(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(BackgroundColor)
            .padding(12.dp)
    ) {
        Coordinates(modifier)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Coordinates(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = Modifier
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Email,
            contentDescription = "email icon"
        )
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.mail_adress),
            fontSize = 20.sp
        )
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun VisitCardPreview() {
    CarteDeVisite2Theme {
        VisitCard()
    }
}

And the result not cropped:


most probably this is some other issue, I used the same code and it is working.

Image looks to be cropped from the right side. Post a full image to help understand the issue

@MarekMacko Thanks for your answer, I added a full image of my problem

@stallianz Thanks for your answer, I added the full code if needed.

It could be an issue with the preview. You'll need to verify by installing the app & turning on the Show layout bounds in Developer options on your phone.

@dev.tejasb was right, it was an issue with the preview. Thanks!
